# Values calculated by identical matrices in different representations don't match (using numpy.linalg.eigh)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Please bear with me I know it's a long text to read but I've been strugling for several days now and can't seem to make it work, although I think the solution must be pretty simple I can't seem to find it.

I'm working in Python. I would use smaler sizes, but these sizes are the lowest at which my problem appears.
My program models a lattice with 5 places, at each place there can be either a zero or a one. I'm looking at the two cases where I place three and two ones onto my lattice.
I have two Matrices. The first one are all possibilities to put two ones on an array of length 5 the second one are all to put three ones on an array of length 5:

```
occupation_three = 
[[ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.  1.  0.]]
occupation_two = 
[[ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  1.  0.]]
```

(I generated these using a function i wrote for variable number of ones and array length)
Now I formed a Matrix using these occupation matrices as input(for those with a bit of physics knowledge, these following matrices are the Hamiltonians):

```
hamilton_three:
[[ 0.25  1.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    0.  ]
 [ 1.   -0.75  1.    0.    0.    1.    0.    1.    0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    1.    0.25  0.    1.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.25  1.    0.    0.    1.    0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    1.    1.   -0.75  1.    0.    0.    1.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    1.    0.    0.    1.   -0.75  1.    0.    0.    1.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    0.25  1.    0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    1.    0.    1.    0.    0.    1.   -0.75  1.    0.  ]
 [ 1.    0.    0.    0.    1.    0.    0.    1.   -0.75  1.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    0.    0.    1.    0.25]]
hamilton_two:
[[ 0.25  1.    0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    0.    0.    0.  ]
 [ 1.   -0.75  1.    0.    1.    0.    0.    0.    1.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    1.   -0.75  1.    0.    1.    0.    1.    0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    1.    0.25  0.    0.    1.    0.    0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    1.    0.    0.    0.25  1.    0.    0.    0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    1.    0.    1.   -0.75  1.    0.    0.    1.  ]
 [ 1.    0.    0.    1.    0.    1.   -0.75  0.    1.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    1.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.25  1.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    1.    0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    1.   -0.75  1.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    0.    0.    1.    0.25]]
```

Up to here everything including the hamilton matrices should be correct, I checked it manually calculating them with pen and paper.
As you can see, the occupation matrices have the same rows, if you switch zeros and ones, just in another order. The process, with which I generated the hamilton matrices delivers the same matrix if one switches the ones and the zeros in the input matrix, i.e. if the rows (that would equal each other when switched) in the occupation matrices would be in the same order, then the hamilton matrices would be the same.
Because of this the two big hamilton matrices are the same matrix, just in another basis. If i calculate their eigenvalues and eigenvectors using numpy.linalg.eigh (since the matrices are symmetric):

```
eigenval_three, eigenvec_three = np.linalg.eigh(hamilton_three)
eigenval_two, eigenvec_two = np.linalg.eigh(hamilton_two)
```

**The eigenvalues are the same for both hamilton matrices** (this confirms the fact that they are indeed the same, just in another basis):

```
[-3.14025688 -3.14025688 -1.31155281 -0.58785279 -0.58785279  0.70588678
  0.70588678  1.0222229   1.0222229   2.81155281]
```

Now comes the problem: **I want to calculate the expectation value for the number that sits at the third position of my lattice.** I'm doing this for each eigenvector. I will first describe it in some kind of pseudocode: (Notice that each entry of the eigenvector belongs to the row of the occupation matrix with the same index):

sum over all values val_i with i from 1 to 10.
val_i = take entry in row i from the eigenvector and multiply it by itself, then multiply it by the value in the third column of the ith row of the occupation matrix.

```
def expectation_value(eigenvector, occupationmatrix):
    sum = 0.0
    for i in range(len(eigenvector)):
        sum += occupationmatrix[i,2] * (abs(eigenvec[i]))** 2
    return sum
```

From a physical/mathmatical point of view, the expectation values of the three matrix, should be the same as 1-expectationval of the two matrix, but for some reason this isn't the case:

```
    expectation_val_three = np.empty(len(eigenval_three))
    for i in range(len(eigenval_three)):
        expectation_val_three[i] = expectation_value(eigenvec_three.T[i], occupation_three)

    expectation_val_two = np.empty(len(eigenval_two))
    for i in range(len(eigenval_two)):
        expectation_val_two[i] = 1 - expectation_value(eigenvec_two.T[i], occupation_two)
```

(I use .T because the eigenvectors are the colums not the rows of the return value of eigh)

This gives me:

```
expectation_val_three= 
[ 0.40531834  0.79468166  0.6         0.59774245  0.60225755  0.75801321
  0.44198679  0.56227678  0.63772322  0.6       ]
expectation_val_two)=
[ 0.79468166  0.40531834  0.6         0.58934802  0.61065198  0.62080767
  0.57919233  0.56725061  0.63274939  0.6       ]
```

**Some values are pretty close but others are way of**. Thanks to anyone who read this far, maybe you have some idea, why the expectation values don't match, I would highly appreciate it. Thanks in advance! (Maybe it has something to do with some numerical error or something like that)

Comment: I don't have a proper answer but are you sure this is a programming problem?  Since 8 of your eigenvalues come in degenerate pairs (arising I suspect from a symmetry between +ve and -ve "momentum" states) the eigenvectors are ambiguous - any linear combination of vectors with the degenerate eigenvalues being as good as any other - and if the solver picks inequivalent vectors for your Hs the expectation of your occupation number could be different.  (Note for the mom 0 states, with 0.6 occupation probability, the two Hs behave as you expect.)

Comment: @Mike Dinsdale hmm that's a very very good point. Thanks for taking the time and reading it all. (I posted it here since i thought that the problem was somewhere in my coding or that someone might know if the errors lie in the internal rounding errors of python.) But if the eigenvectors are all orthogonal and normalized, shouldn't then the expectation values still be the same for the same energy, just by physical reasoning?

Comment: It's a bit confusing but I don't think the expectation values will generally be the same!  The simplest basis for the pair of states with a given E would be the "momentum" eigenstates, i.e. eigenstates of a cyclic shift having eigenvalues exp(+/- 2pi*i*n/5) (n = 1 or 2).  In these the probability of any particular occupation pattern is independent of its position (the amplitude for each position is a varying unit complex number).  But orthogonal linear combinations of these, constrained to have real amplitudes in your basis, will have amplitudes that vary like cos(2pi i j/5), sin(2pi i j/5).

Comment: Here j is the position relative to an arbitrary start point (this is the ambiguity which might be giving the difference between your Hs).  What I think this does mean is that the average expectation value should always by 0.6 (since the prob for each occupation state is a sum of cos^2 values for one eigenstate and sin^2 values for the other) which does agree with your data.  Anyway must admit I haven't properly checked all this but hopefully if you look at the eigenvectors you'll see if it makes sense or not!